Keyboard problem in my laptop
I'm using asus laptop and I am using Ubuntu desktop 24.04 LTS.
After updating and upgrading with apt I'm facing issues. Like
when I enter "e" button on keyboard it will display "space e" and
when I hit "h" button it will show me "nh" and "n" button "nh"
and "b" button "bg" and "g" "bg".
How to get rid of this problem?

im using ubuntu desktop
